# COMSOL magnetic field time dependent

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, computational-physics, software

enter image description here

I need to modelling conductor in Comsol 5.3 by MF physics in Time Dependent study

Conductor model "Single conductor" in "Coil" feature doesn't work in TD study, and Homogenized multi-turn (with 1 turn) ignores skin-effect.

If i used "External current density" it gets me error "Last step dont convergenced"

How can I set the desired current pulse?

Current pulse: rate of rise and fall 100 kA/us, ampl - 100 A
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic because it's about using a particular software and not physics.

Comment: It is better to post this question in COMSOL community forum: https://www.comsol.com/community/  You shall get pretty quick and correct responses generally.